# how to fetch all the tags in particular Response array for a nested xml using groovy script for soap ui 5.3.0

Tags: groovy, soapui

I want to fetch all the values for particular array, how can we do that?

I used the below one, but it only reads the 1st parameter not the entire parameters of the array.

```
def ActualValue= resholder.getNodeValues("//*:Array1//*:"+context["parameter"]).toString()
```

there are 10 parameters in a particular array, and after fetching value of 1st node, am getting error as "java.lang.nullpointerexception: Cannot invoke method contains () on null object"

```
<a:Bundle> 
  <a:Plans> 
    <a:Quotes> 
      <a:Quote>
        <a:StandardBenefits>
          <a:BenefitPeriod>
            <a:Description i:nil="true"/>
            <a:DisplayName i:nil="true"/>
            <a:Value>6 months</a:Value>
          </a:BenefitPeriod>
          <a:Coinsurance>
            <a:Description>50</a:Description>
            <a:DisplayName i:nil="true"/>
            <a:Value>50</a:Value>
          </a:Coinsurance>                                       
          <a:OutOfPocket>
            <a:Description>5000</a:Description>
            <a:DisplayName i:nil="true"/>
            <a:Value>5000</a:Value>
          </a:OutOfPocket>
          <a:PreventiveCare i:nil="true"/>
          <a:Rx i:nil="true"/>
          <a:StopLoss>
            <a:Description i:nil="true"/>
            <a:DisplayName i:nil="true"/>
            <a:Value>10000</a:Value>
          </a:StopLoss>
        </a:StandardBenefits>
      </a:Quote> 
      <a:Quote>
        //similar data like above quote
      </a:Quote>
    </a:Quotes> 
  </a:Plans> 
</a:Bundle>
```

Comment: Can you provide the sample response ? By the way what are you trying to achieve? What is your use case?

Comment: this is the sample xml added here.

Comment: SD31, I could not see the sample. Use `edit` option and add the same to the question.

Comment: <a:Bundle> 
<a:Plans> 
<a:Quotes> 
<a:Quote>
<a:StandardBenefits>                                    
<a:OutOfPocket>
 <a:Description>5000</a:Description>
    <a:DisplayName i:nil="true"/>
       <a:Value>5000</a:Value>
          </a:OutOfPocket>
          <a:PreventiveCare i:nil="true"/>
          <a:Rx i:nil="true"/>
    <a:StopLoss>
 <a:Description i:nil="true"/>
 <a:DisplayName i:nil="true"/>
   <a:Value>10000</a:Value>
  </a:StopLoss>
 </a:StandardBenefits>
</a:Quote> 
<a:Quote>
 //similar data like above quote
      </a:Quote>
    </a:Quotes> 
  </a:Plans>

Comment: Please post the formatted xml in your question by editing.

Comment: hi Rao, have updated the question with XML.

Comment: I want to fetch all the tags of the <a:BenefitPeriod> array, store in excel and compare the values with database value . using the above code, I can only fetch 1st parameter of the array and exists the assertion with null pointer exception error

Comment: Do you want to check these [sample scripts](https://github.com/nmrao/soapUIGroovyScripts/tree/master/groovy/compare) and try it first and update the question?

Comment: thank you for the scripts Rao. am exactly looking for the mistake am doing with the below piece of code, or similar alternative. As I am using excel, where the database response are already stored. my challenge is to fetch the array value, store it and compare it with the values stored in database.    "def ActualValue= resholder.getNodeValues("//*:Array1//*:"+context["parameter"]).toString()"

Comment: Why is it required to bring in another piece into this while it can be achieved without need of it?

Comment: thanks Rao. Now the issue has been resolved using the above piece only "def ActualValue= resholder.getNodeValues("//*:Array1//*:"+context["parameter"‌​])" . It was .toString() which was giving error.

Comment: Glad you could find the resolution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"def ActualValue= resholder.getNodeValues("//*:Array1//*:"+context["parameter"‌​‌​])"

used the above code, for retrieving all the tag values of an array